# Many-to-many relationship using 2 grids in the same form

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to AX, so it could be a simple question.

Imagine two tables **Users** and **Groups** in many-to-many relationship:

- One user can belongs to many groups.
- One group can belongs to many users.

So, I created 3 tables in AX, to represent this relationship:

- **User**
- **Group**
- **GroupUser** (intermediate table used to create the many-to-many relationship with PKs from User and Group tables)

Now imagine I have a form with 2 grids.

Each grid has only one column not editable.
One grid with the Users list (with the User table defined as DataSource) and another with the Group list (with the Group table defined as DataSource).

**Everything is displaying fine, but I would like to have the behaviour that when selecting a Group just appears the Users it belongs, and them I can select the user.**

How to do this last part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing users belonging to a group involves using an `exists join` on the `GroupUser` table.

It was not clear to me from your description, whether this was the case always or only when a group was selected.

Make a new form datasource using `GroupUser` with `JoinMode` set `ExistsJoin` and linked to the `User` table.

If only filtered when a group is selected, make the `GroupUser` datasource disabled:

```
user_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(GroupUser)).enabled(<group is selected>);
```